# Two separate pipelines in gstreamer

Tags: gstreamer

I have two different sources one for audio and other for video. I use appsrc to extract data from the source. I am able to play both video and audio individually. However, I am not sure how to make them work together.

Please let me know if anyone has done this before or knows how two get this done.

Answer (score 1):

You can make them part of the same pipeline. A pipeline can have two sources and two sinks and intermediate components connecting the source to the sink. This way they will use the same pipeline clock.

EDIT:
 audio driving something does not mean that both don't need the same clock. Unless you don;t care for Audio-Video synchronization, ultimately both have to use the same clock. Audio driving something is something seperate so don't mix those two in your head. If you dont want them to use the same clock why do you say "i am not sure how to make them work together" Then they are just independent pipelines and there is no question of running them together. If you want AV synchronization you need clock synchronization. Either doing through rtsp [a long elaborate path not needed at all] or just run both on the same pipeline.

Comment: I don't want them to use the same clock. The audio pipeline has to drive the things for me and so the clock would come from it. I am not able to figure out how to get that done.

Comment: @av501: I have created two separate pipelines now. There are two appsrc element one each for video and audio. The way I expect them to behave is that the master clock should come from the audio pipeline and the video should follow it. I would prefer some video frames being dropped in case of a synchronization lag. 

I have been trying to incorporate the same but have not achieved any success yet. If I add them to the same pipeline then also I wont be able to make audio my master clock. Both audio and video would basically follow the pipeline's clock.

Let me know your view on this.

Comment: There is no seperate pipeline clock. The audio is the master in any av system. The source / sinks drive the clock. Audio will become the master

Comment: How does the pipeline know that the data that is being passed through it is audio. I mean, i am using two separate appsrc elements one get audio data and the other gets video data. As far as my understanding goes I have to somehow make the master clock as the clock of the audio element(sink/source) or there is way through which I let the pipeline know the same.

Comment: Got it. And my previous comment is a bit wrong.  Yes, you have to make the master clock. Does http://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/data/doc/gstreamer/head/gstreamer/html/GstClock.html not help? There is a master/slave synchornization hint given at the end.  However I am not 100% sure on it. The way I look at it is that your sources must produce data and this data is timestamped to the time when it was generated. So automatically all the video samples and audio samples will get synchronized based on these timestamps. There is no master/slave here.

Comment: Dropping logic must be explicitly added in the plugin where you want drop the audio. If you have rtsp at the end, change the logic in the plugins there.

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure if it stills a question but if anyone interested in, I have found a solution for this from Gstreamer tutorials given below. It uses two pipelines with one source.

https://gstreamer.freedesktop.org/documentation/tutorials/basic/multithreading-and-pad-availability.html?gi-language=c